# XY scatter chart and points connected with arrows

Tags: windows-7, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I'd like to plot annual Sales data on the X-axis and the corresponding Profit data on the Y-axis. To highlight which point is the latest and which the oldest and how Sales and Profit developed over time I'd like to connect the dots with arrows.

In older versions of Excel that was quite simple. In Excel 2016 I can only see an arrow at the latest data point, but not for each and every prior data point.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert very small gaps between the endpoints of the arrows and their destination points. And set in excel that gaps are not shown.
Follow this routine:
https://peltiertech.com/connect-two-xy-series-with-arrows/